# Azure DevOps - linking to an email from a work item

Tags: email, azure-devops

In our team we simply want to link to existing e-mails. I see many explanations online on how to make an automated procedure that triggers when an e-mail comes in, but that's not what we want.

We simply want to link to an e-mail in our inbox in the work item.

Something like 'Refers to: *'e-mail'*' .

Comment: Your best bet is probably the message-id header in the emails (hope that no program messes with it and it's in fact unique).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, it's not supported to link work items with existing emails.

Link types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops

You may add the links of emails to Description as a workaround.

[image]

In addition, you could add a custom field to support tracking data requirements you have that aren't met with the existing set of fields. Please refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops